# Radgrid row background change based on checkbox value in radgrid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, telerik-grid

I have a radgrid in which I am trying to set the row background color based on whether or not a checkbox is checked (boolean value). I have the code here:

```
If(TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem) Then 
     dim dataItem as GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)
     If (dataItem("Inactive").Text = 1) then 
           dataItem.CssClass = "DisposedAssetRowColor"
     End IF
End IF
```

It is based on a boolean value so i think I need to somehow make the dataItem an integer value so i can then check it against 1 or 0 to set the background color but I don't know how to. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar

On the Item data Bound event try the following code

```
If (TypeOf (e.Item) Is GridDataItem) Then
    Dim s As CheckBox
    s = CType(e.Item.Cells(1).Controls(0), CheckBox)
    If s.Checked Then
        e.Item.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
End If
```

Where e As GridItemEventArgs

And e.Item.Cells(1).Controls(0) = The column where you have the check box